# Eliminating static properties - What patterns do I have at my disposal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, c#-4.0

I currently have a type that I inject into my controllers that's used for getting and setting session data.

I use this so that I can obtain relevant session information as `_sessionData.Username` rather than using `Session["username"]`.

I'd like to use this session information across all of my views and would previously have done this by making the SessionData members static instead of injecting the SessionData class into my controller.

I want to avoid using static members as well as having to pass the object to the view in each controller.

What patterns best suit this type of scenario? What do you do to solve this same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use Session["username"]? You can wrap the static call in an instance like this:

```
public class MySessionClass
{
    public string GetSessionValue(String value)
    {
        return Session[value];
    }
}
```

You gain the maintenance and flexibility of an instance that can then be mocked in a test without having to rewrite the Session class over again

**UPDATE**

As far as using your instance in your view, what is stopping you from writing a code-block and newing it up and using it? You should be able to write code against it like any other code nuggets in MVC. **However**, I would suggest against doing this as it defeats the purpose of tiering your architecture. You can either access the session directly, like you would with any HTML page, or you can pass it through as an object from your controller.

Comment: I prefer knowing exactly what I have access to in the session rather than using magic key strings. My SessionData class does pretty much what your method above does. The question is, how do I use this inside my views without making it static?

Comment: Thanks Justin. So far none of the solutions I know of seem very elegant. Accessing static class members, using magic strings to access the session object directly, newing up objects in the view. There's got to be a more elegant way to access shared information across a multitude of views. Perhaps using a base controller to insert the custom Session class into the view bag for each request.

Comment: @JamieDixon What about my other suggestion of using your instance to receive the data and pass it to the view? Otherwise, you end up blending the UI with the logic, which you should avoid

Comment: It makes sense but again it just seems a bit unelegant. Take for example the username at the top of this page. That's probably coming from a shared view _Layout.cshtml or similar. Passing that data in every controller seems like overkill.

Comment: @JamieDixon Yes, and they are probably using the static session for that. This is the UI view, which is supposed to be stateless, so you can only access static values in that context. I do not think it is not elegant because otherwise, as already stated, you are blending too much logic into your UI

Comment: Thanks for helping Justin. I do appreciate it. Perhaps there just isn't a more elegant way of sharing this information than directly hitting the Session object from my views. I'll have more of a think and if I come up with a nice solution I'll be sure to write about it.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection would help you here. Take any dependency injection framework and integrate it with you MVC application. For example to integrate Ninject into you MVC application see this [blog post](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3/).

Once you integrate a DI framework with you application. Register the SessionData class with the DI framework. Choose a valid lifetime for the SessionData class based on your scenario. If you look at these DI frameworks they provide multiple lifetime configurations such as instance per call, per session, singleton.

Now inject SessionData dependency where ever you want. For controller you can create a BaseController containing this dependency as a public property such as

```
[Inject]
public SessionData SessionContext {get;set;}
```

For View part you need to look at passing [strongly typed model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx). The process would be similar here. Create a BaseModel, keep a SessionData property here and DI framework should do the rest. The last step here would be to pass this model to each view rendered.

Comment: Please see my answer and the comments, this is what has already been suggested and the OP is unhappy with it.

Comment: Thanks @Chandermani. I'm already using dependecy injection and as Justin said already, he covered most of the known ways of passing the data to the view. See my comments on his answer if you want more info. My question was probably a bit unclear.